# what is different between head node and other nodes in sending them to function?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm learning linked list and I saw this code about removing nodes from linked list:

```
struct Node {
    char* data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* head = NULL;
void delete(int index) {//not removing head node
    if (head == NULL)
    {
      printf("error no info!")
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = find(head, index - 1);//this function will find position of node we want to delete and check if position existed in list

            Node* t = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            free(t);
            return;
    }
}
void RemoveHead(Node** head)
{
    Node* temp = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = temp;
}
```

I don't understand why for inserting or removing a node from first of the list I need to send `**head` to my functions otherwise it won't work `(void RemoveHead)` ,but for other nodes of list sending `*head` will do good `(void delete1)`.

can you explain this to me? thanks for help.

Comment: It is possible to write a function that will delete any node from the list, but the current `delete` function is poorly implemented.

Comment: @IanAbbott you're right. it's not a good code. it's just something to show when we send `**head` to those functions(you mentioned). it's because of first node not others.

Comment: As an alternative, delete() could return an updated head pointer to node, in which case the calling code would update its copy of head, and delete() would only need "node * head" as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume here that the signature of `delete` is actually `void delete(Node *head, int index);` and that you have `void RemoveHead(Node** head);` for the first node.

The difference is that `RemoveHead` has to change the value of the `head` pointer. As C passes all parameters by value, you must pass the address of any output parameter. Because of that you must give `RemoveHead` the address of the pointer hence the different signature.

By contrast, `delete` only *uses* the value of the `head` pointer, and it keeps its value at function return, so there is no need to pass the address.

Comment: Thanks, you really explained it well.